# Convergence of graphs vs pointwise convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are compact metric spaces. Let $C(X,Y)$ be the set of continuous maps $f:X\to Y$. For $f\in C(X,Y)$, the graph of $f$ is closed in $X\times Y$. Suppose that $\{f^n\}$ is a sequence in $C(X,Y)$ and suppose that the corresponding sequence of graphs converges to a closed set in $X\times Y$ in the Hausdorff metric topology. Does that imply that there exists a map $f:X\to Y$ that is the pointwise limit of some subsequence of the sequence of functions $\{f^n\}$?

Comment: Let $A_n$ be the graph of $f^n$. What do you mean by "$A_n$ converges to a closed set in $X\times Y$?

Comment: View the closed subsets of $X\times Y$ as a metric space with the Hausdorff metric between sets. For the definition of the Hausdorff distance, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#Definition Now view the sequence $\{f^n\}$ as the corresponding sequence of graphs (closed sets) in $X\times Y$ and assume that this sequence converges to a closed set in $X\times Y$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Comment: @ChoF. I have also seen this called the Hausdorff-Besicovich metric... BTW  if M is a compact metric space the Hausdorff metric is complete.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are right. It is a complete metric space. Thanks for the information "the Hausdorff-Besicovich metric".

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]** OP required that the graph of the limit funtion need not be the same as the limit of the closed sets.

Let $X=Y=[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\subset\mathbb{R}$, and consider the sequence
$$
\bigl\{ f_{2n}(x)=\operatorname{arctan}((2n)x) \mid n\geq 1 \bigr\}
$$
[image]

and
$$
\bigl\{ f_{2n-1}(x)=\operatorname{arctan}((2n-1)x-1) \mid n\geq 1 \bigr\}
$$
[image]

Then the graph of $f_n$ converges to the union of three line segments,
$$
\bigl([-\frac{\pi}{2},0]\times\{-\frac{\pi}{2}\}\bigr) \cup \bigl(\{0\}\times[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\bigr) \cup \bigl([0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\times\{\frac{\pi}{2}\}\bigr)
$$
But the sequence $\{f_n\}$ does not converge at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Note that the limit is indeed a closed set in $X\times Y$, and that there is a map $f:X\to Y$, defined as $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x<0$, and $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ if $x>0$, that is the pointwise limit of $\{f^n\}$.

Comment: I see. It requires that the graph of the limit funtion need not be the same as the limit of the closed sets.

Comment: Right, this is a possibility, as illustrated by your example.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Note however that there is a subsequence that converges pointwise.

Comment: @mo15 You are right. I wonder that there is any counter-example. Maybe it is better to find a proof.